# Performant zend pagination without zend_db_select

Tags: php, performance, zend-framework, pagination

This is just an example, but most of the queries in my application are like this:

```
public function getCommentsByPost($postid)
{
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM comments c
        LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = c.comment_userid
        WHERE c.comment_postid = ?';
$statement = $db->query($sql, array($postid));
$rows = $statement->fetchAll();
$comment = null;
foreach($rows as $row){
    $comment = new Model_Comment();
    $comment->populate($row);
    $this->list[] = $comment;
}
return $this->getList();
}
```

I don't use zend_db_select because usually there are a lot of joins involved and the queries are quite complicated. But I need to add pagination for my page listing, and I'm afraid that using the array adapter won't be very effective, because Zend will select every row from my 'posts' table. Are there any ways around this, or should I implement my own pagination functionality?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way of getting an SQL string into the Zend Select object. You'd need an SQL parser for that and ZF doesn't have that.

You'd have to refactor the statements into the Zend Select object, this can be very annoying and difficult at times, I didn't do it on my first ZF project. I wish I had done now as it is the best way of doing it and ensures you can take advantage of all the extras, E.g. pagination.

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar to the following with a zend_db_select model and it works with zend pagination

```
$select = $this->model->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$select->where('table1.field = ?', $field)
       ->join('table2','table1.field = table2.feild')
       ->where('table2.field = ?', $field)
       ->order('field DESC');
$object = $this->model->fetchAll($select);
```